# Invalid JSON response block editor

Tags: php, wordpress, editor, shortcode

When I add this shortcode that I created, on a page, the code works fine and as expected.  But when I want to edit the page in Block editor, there is a message that states "Invalid JSON response block editor".

I'm not extremely concerned, but will someone please have a look at my code and let me know if the problem lies with my code, or if it is just a glitch with the block editor?

Am I perhaps missing brackets somewhere {}

Thank you

````
function gk_username( $current_user ) { 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
}

add_shortcode( 'gk_user', 'gk_username');

/*Use this shortcode: [gk_user]*/```
````

Comment: Looks like you need to return a value in your function.

Comment: @Aida Thank you for your assistance.  I tried to add the following before the closing } bracket, but it made it worst.  If I add `return $current_user;` it says "There is a critical error on this website.  What is the proper way to return the two values?  Thank you

Comment: @ Aida  Thank you.  You were right.  I had to return the value instead of echo'ing

Comment: please add your solution and mark it as answer. Also, please keep voting up for the helpful comments and answers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Aida

Thank you, you helped me to figure it out.  Instead of echoing the result, it must be returned because a shortcode is being created.

So I changed the code to the following and there are no more errors and it is working.  Thank you.

````
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    return 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
}

add_shortcode( 'gk_user', 'gk_username');

/*Use this shortcode: [gk_user]*/ ```
````